# Fastest way of running GridSearchCV with multiple CPUs

Tags: python, scikit-learn, parallel-processing, joblib

I need to perform `GridSearchCV` with 4 different classifiers. I have at my disposal 128 CPUs which i can use in different sessions (2 sessions with 64CPus, 4 sessions with 32 CPUs, etc).

I'd like to ask if there's any way of knowing which could be faster:

- Run 1 session w/ 128CPus 4 times;
- Run 2 sessions w/ 64CPUs in parallell 2 times;
- Run 4 sessions w/ 32CPUs in parallel 1 time.

Comment: As of now this question seems quite theoretic. How about benchmarking yourself and then discussing the results here? I bet that would yield better results / answer.

Comment: Seems like a `Predictive benchmarking` problem...

Answer (score 0):

Given the little information you have shared and without any code, my answer to you is:

> It depends on a number of factors, but to name the most important ones, I would focus on the steps of your pipeline that can create bottlenecks.

Per example, let's say that one of your steps is an embedding algorithm that transforms your data using just 1 CPU, because the parallelism is not possible, and it is a step that takes a very long time. Then, in this scenario it would be actually more beneficial to have 128 sessions with 1 CPU at a time (this is a worse case scenario, because it would require a lot of parameters definition, but in your example it would be 4 sessions w/ 32CPUs in parallel 1 time)

If on the other hand, most of your pipeline steps are really fast to process (parallelised or not) but your classifier is the bottleneck, then you need to make use of parallelism. In this scenario I would say it would be more beneficial to use 1 session with 128 CPUs at a time.

I don't think this is your case, but if on the other hand, you have a very small amount of data, then probably the benefit of parallelism would be offset by the overhead operation of distribution of the data.

I would say it is better for you to measure how long each step takes using a small amount of data (and then also upscale a bit) to gather a grasp for how all this things behave before doing the full training.